# TypeScript functions within functions vs. private functions

Tags: typescript, oop, encapsulation, readability, information-hiding

**Here is a hypothetical example:**

I have a `market.service.ts` with 2 functions called `buy()` and `sell()` which are each 100 lines of code

```js
export class ShopService {
  public async buy() {
    // 100 lines of code
  }
  public async sell() {
    // 100 lines of code
  }
}
```

I want to refactor these two into 2 main functions which each will call some mini functions. Each of these two are being called in a controller, so i can not change the public api for this service and `buy()` and `sell()` should have the same api.

**Here is my question:**

What are the pros and cons of each of these approaches? (for context, my main concern is code readability and not performance at all cost! also, this class has 100% test coverage)

**Here are the two approaches i can take for this:**

1. I can define the mini functions as private functions inside this service class and just **call them once**.

```js
export class ShopService {
  public async buy() {
    this.checkBuyMarket();
    this.checkIfUserCanBuy();
    this.makeTheBuyOrder();
  }
  public async sell() {
    this.checkSellMarket();
    this.checkIfUserCanSell();
    this.makeTheSellOrder();
  }

  private async checkSellMarket() {
    //30 lines of code
  }
  private async checkBuyMarket() {
    //30 lines of code
  }
  private async checkIfUserCanBuy() {
    //30 lines of code
  }
  private async checkIfUserCanSell() {
    //30 lines of code
  }
  private async makeTheBuyOrder() {
    //30 lines of code
  }
  private async makeTheSellOrder() {
    //30 lines of code
  }
}
```

2. I can define these functions that are **called only once**, within buy() or sell() and call them there.

```js
export class ShopService {
  public async buy() {
    checkBuyMarket();
    checkIfUserCanBuy();
    makeTheBuyOrder();

    async function checkBuyMarket() {
      //30 lines of code
    }
    async function checkIfUserCanBuy() {
      //30 lines of code
    }
    async function makeTheBuyOrder() {
      //30 lines of code
    }
  }
  public async sell() {
    checkSellMarket();
    checkIfUserCanSell();
    makeTheSellOrder();

    async function checkSellMarket() {
      //30 lines of code
    }
    async function checkIfUserCanSell() {
      //30 lines of code
    }
    async function makeTheSellOrder() {
      //30 lines of code
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you want to add unit tests for the "mini" functions I think it would only work with approach 1. Other than that, I feel like this question is opinion-based.

Comment: Between these two, I'd choose 1. for similar concern as what @JSONDerulo expressed. However, realistically I'd decompose this functionality further and extract he "mini functions" into at least one other module. Maybe even multiple. Makes the testing easier and makes future changes easier. You can even have different alternative implementations of, say, `makeTheSellOrder` and use one or the other based on some different conditions (strategies).

Comment: Please don't close this as opinion-based. The final verdict to such questions may be opinion-based, but a list of arguments can be created objectively and contains points that programmers need to consider.

Comment: @julaine i strongly agree with you. that's why i asked for pros and cons of each approach and not which is better. the better approach can change based on use case, but the pros and cons are facts and will not change.

Answer (score 4):

I strongly recommend version 1, and I do not think this is opinion-based. **Version 2 wrongly communicates an intent and a complication that you do not have**, and this is objectively a readability-issue.

The problem is that to understand an inner function, you must read the whole enclosing function, too, making your `buy` and `sell` functions effectively 100-line functions. Why is that?

Defining a function `h` inside a function `f` allows you to:

- access local variables of `f`
- return the function `h` with the captured variables local to `f` to be used outside of `f`
- use `h` as a callback-argument to APIs that `f` uses, making use of local variables in `f`

All are legitimate programming techniques, but they make `f` and `h` more complex to understand. Now, if `h` does not do any of that, a reader will *think* that some of these must be happening, so they have to scan the whole source-code of `f` and `h` to see that this is not happening. Worse: a maintainer might think it OK to modify `h` or `f` in such a way that they do do some of these three things, and it won't be easily visible in the diff, making your mental model of the functions wrong.

Comment: Related to "*access local variables of `f`*" - this makes `h` *impure*. And the follow-up text explains the impact of that - it's harder to reason about. However, a trivial transformation can make `h` pure and vastly clarify its meaning - instead of using any variables in scope, it has to *declare them as parameters*. That transforms `h` into a pure function, makes it eligible for extraction and is more up-front in declaring what it relies upon.

Comment: @VLAZ good point, I wanted to avoid the words pure/impure because in the context of object methods they might already be impure. If the functions are pure or can be made pure than I would think they should be extracted out of the class, to make it obvious they have no access to the fields of the class.

Answer (score 2):

Both approaches have their pros and cons, and the choice between them often comes down to personal preference and the specific context of your project. But as you said your priority is code readability then I would say you should prefer Private Methods. It has code readability, and code can be reused and can also encapsulate.

Ensure that you're not introducing code duplication. If similar logic is needed in both buy and sell, consider refactoring common functionality into shared private methods. Also, a good practice is to use private methods for more complex logic and using inline functions for simpler steps.

Comment: is this a good use for your last point? 

i have multiple cases which should throw exceptions, i can move all of them into `throwExceptionIfInvalid()` and call it inside the original function.